# I am trying to display a html file using res.sendFile in express

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

i am trying to implement a work flow, where, when the user logs in, the user credentials is posted to one of the routes in express via ajax to check if the user exists, if the user exists, the express route will send back a message "authorised" to the ajax call, and the success callback is invoked where another ajax call sends a header along with data to the express route(/reroute). This express /reroute api is trying to res.redirect to another route /homepage. Inside the  /homepage route i am attempting to display a html file using res.sendfile, and the res.sendfile is not working.

my login ajax call

```
$(document).on("click", "#login", (e) => {
const email = $('#logemail').val().trim();
const pass = $('#password').val().trim();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:4000/checkuserexists",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
        email: email,
        pass: pass
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.message === "authorised") {
            const token = request.getResponseHeader('access-token');
            localStorage.setItem("access-token", token);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:4000/reroute",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('access-token', token);
                },
                data: {
                    redirectTo: 'homepage'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data + " from ajax  ")
                }
            })
        } else {
            $('.alertbox').show();
            $('.alertbox').text("User unauthorised");
        }
    }
})
```

})

my express route (/reroute)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
if (req.header('access-token')) {
    const token = req.header('access-token');
    const redirectTo = req.query.redirectTo;
    if (redirectTo === 'homepage') {
        res.setHeader('access-token', token)
        res.redirect('/homepage')
      }
    }
  })


   module.exports = router;
```

my homepage route

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const token_middleware = require('../middlewares/jwtauth');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")))
router.get('/', token_middleware, (req, res) => {
if (req.status === "exists") {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/homepage.html"));
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
}
  })
   module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the URL with Ajax.

The browser asks for `/reroute` and gets a redirect to `/homepage`.

It then asks for `/homepage` and gets an HTML document.

It passes that HTML document to the JavaScript engine and jQuery tries to parse it as JSON (it ignores the `Content-Type` because you said `dataType: "JSON"`) and errors.

---

If you want to do this with Ajax, then don't redirect. Return some JSON that tells your code the login was successful. Then you can navigate with client-side JS and the `location` object.

If you want to redirect, then use a regular form submission and not Ajax.

Comment: sir i did as you have directed, i removed the dataType property, but still the res.sendFile inside my homepage route is not displaying anything

Comment: Reread the answer. At no point did I say that removing `dataType` would fix the problem. (Although doing so should remove the error and cause the success function to run and log the HTML to the developer tools console).

Comment: i am sorry sir, yes i did remove the dataType property and i received the html data to my dev console, but i want the res.sendFile to display the page, not send back data to my ajax call

Comment: "yes i did remove the dataType property and i received the html data to my dev console" - That's what I said would happen.

Comment: "i want the res.sendFile to display the page, not send back data to my ajax call" — Then try doing one of the things I suggested in the answer.